# Всплывающая подсказка swift

Tags: swift

как можно сделать что-то вроде всплывающей подсказки при переходе на новую сцену, чтобы автоматически один раз появилась и все?
пытаюсь сделать через алерт, но может проще есть способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я предлагаю использовать тебе этот метод

```
let defaults1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var  count1 = defaults.integerForKey("count3") ?? 0
if count1 == 0 {  // каждые 40 вход
   showAlert(count1)
}
count1 += 1
defaults1.setInteger(count1, forKey: "count3")
```

этот метод будет использоваться только один раз при первом запуске.

а вот пример алерта.

```
func showAlert(count:Int) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Внимание", message: "Если у Вас возникают проблемы в работе приложения, Вы можете оповестить нас об этом, выбрав пункт «Оповестить об ошибке» в правом верхнем углу экрана.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    // show the alert

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Удачи.